# Error in generate programming file in xilinx EDK

Tags: xilinx, xilinx-edk, xilinx-ise

while working on Xilinx EDK to  implement a simple design using embedded softcore IP, we have hit a few hurdles, following is the detailed outline of the problems we are facing.

as per our understanding, we followed the following steps involved for a solution using EDK design flow

step 1- Xilinx ISE
                - Create new project
                -add new source - select embedded processor, this will lead to opening of XPS, wherein we can select or create a softcore IP.

step 2- Xilinx Platform Studio (xps)
               -create new board support package (BSP), enter information about softcore IP , peripherals and other details.
               - export hardware design to sdk

step 3- Xilinx SDK
            - Create a Hardware Platform- linking hw
            - Setting up software Environment- creating xilinx C project

Problem-->

I created a project in xilinx ise, then added an embedded processor using xps, but when I am trying to generate programming file, I get the following error.

```
ERROR:EDK - INFO:Security:67 - XILINXD_LICENSE_FILE is set to
   '/opt/Xilinx/12.1/ISE_DS/EDK/data/core_licenses' in /home/h2o/.flexlmrc.
   INFO:Security:68 - Please run the Xilinx License Configuration Manager
   ERROR:Security:14 - No feature was available for 'XPS'.
ERROR:EDK:440 - platgen failed with errors!
ERROR:EDK -  
   Error while running "gmake -f system.make netlist".
ERROR: synthesizing XPS module failed!
```

To remove the gmake error, I have created an link to make  for gmake already, and its there working successfully for sdk, but here it is showing error. to check if link is there or not I ran the "ln" command and got this output

```
h2o@h2o-Vostro-1015:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/make /usr/bin/gmake
[sudo] password for h2o:
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/bin/gmake': File exists
```

Also on the license front I am facing the problem, every time I open xps it shows me that license is not present and opens the xilinx license manager.  I have registered at xilinx website and obtained the .lic license file, only few days ago.

every time I open xps, I have to follow the same process of adding xilinx.lic file (PFB screens for reference.)

[image: error on opening xps]
​

​

[image: adding existing license file]

[image: locating file]

[image: success message]